# Exchange server cannot connect to remote host

Tags: exchange-server, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-server-2013

I have installed a Microsoft Exchange 2013 server on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine. I've installed both Mailbox and Client Access roles. All the prerequisites have been installed. I found a "fix" for this problem (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2027064), but it tells me to run the query **(Get-User username).RemotePowershellEnabled** and **Set-User username -RemotePowerShellEnabled $True** on the Exchange Management Shell; however, I cannot do that since I can't even connect to the server. Can anyone provide any help?

The error I get when I open the Exchange Management shell is the following: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is Windows Firewall off for domain systems on both systems?  There are Windows Firewall requirements that Exchange deployment should mod, but sometimes it doesn't work.  We turned the firewall off (not disable) to get by install issues and turn on after....

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/02/18/exchange-firewalls-and-support-oh-my.aspx

Comment: @Chaseabbott I didn't have any issues during installation though. I reinstalled it on a new machine and I'm getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: A new machine would have the same limitations because by default domain-joined Windows system have firewall on.  Installation wouldn't be affected here.  But moving beyond firewall, I have seen also during installation WIndows services being disabled (normal) but not turing back on properly and staying in a disabled state.  If the WS Management service IS working, then this is still a connectivity issue; even if on the same box as they'll still use the NIC's on the system for internal communication.  IPv6 should NOT be disabled too...